# iOS: Select query return different results on some devices

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite

I am using this code for getting values from DB, it works fine for iPhone 4s and iPhone 5. But when it returns different values in iPhone 5s and onwards. I don't know why is this working like this.

```
  NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

// Setup the database object
sqlite3 *database;
if(!databasePath)
{
    [self getDbPath:_dbName];
}
char const *dbPath = [databasePath UTF8String];

// Open the database from the users filessytem
if(sqlite3_open(dbPath, &database) == SQLITE_OK)
{// Setup the SQL Statement and compile it for faster access

    //SQLIte Statement
    NSString *sqlStatement_userInfo =[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Select * from "]stringByAppendingString:tablename];

    sqlite3_stmt *compiledStatement;


    if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, [sqlStatement_userInfo UTF8String], -1, &compiledStatement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
    {

        // Loop through the results and add them to the feeds array
        while(sqlite3_step(compiledStatement) == SQLITE_ROW)
        {
            CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
            CGFloat screenWidth = screenRect.size.width;
            CGFloat screenHeight = screenRect.size.height;
            if((screenWidth==320 && screenHeight==480) || (screenWidth==320 && screenHeight==568))
            {
                // Init the Data Dictionary
                NSMutableDictionary *_dataDictionary=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

                NSString *colId = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 0)];
                // NSLog(@"_userName = %@",_userName);

                NSString *authcode = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 5)];
                // NSLog(@"_emailID = %@",_emailID);

                NSString *title = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 1)];
                // NSLog(@"_contactNumber = %@",_contactNumber);

                NSString *subtitle = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 4)];

                NSString *hours = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 3)];
                NSString *notificationtype = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 2)];
                [_dataDictionary setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",colId] forKey:@"id"];
                [_dataDictionary setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",authcode] forKey:@"authcode"];
                [_dataDictionary setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",title] forKey:@"title"];
                [_dataDictionary setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",subtitle] forKey:@"subtitle"];

                [_dataDictionary setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",hours] forKey:@"hours"];
                [_dataDictionary setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",notificationtype] forKey:@"notificationtype"];


                [array addObject:_dataDictionary];
            }
            else
            {
                // Init the Data Dictionary
                NSMutableDictionary *_dataDictionary=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

                NSString *colId = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 0)];
                // NSLog(@"_userName = %@",_userName);

                NSString *authcode = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 5)];
                // NSLog(@"_emailID = %@",_emailID);

                NSString *title = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 3)];
                // NSLog(@"_contactNumber = %@",_contactNumber);

                NSString *subtitle = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 4)];

                NSString *hours = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 2)];
                NSString *notificationtype = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 1)];
                [_dataDictionary setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",colId] forKey:@"id"];
                [_dataDictionary setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",authcode] forKey:@"authcode"];
                [_dataDictionary setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",title] forKey:@"title"];
                [_dataDictionary setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",subtitle] forKey:@"subtitle"];

                [_dataDictionary setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",hours] forKey:@"hours"];
                [_dataDictionary setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",notificationtype] forKey:@"notificationtype"];

                // [_dataDictionary setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",hour] forKey:@"ZIPCode"];

                [array addObject:_dataDictionary];
            }

        }
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"No Data Found");
    }

    // Release the compiled statement from memory
    sqlite3_finalize(compiledStatement);
}

sqlite3_close(database);

return array;
```

In above query following code is working fine for 4s and 5 but it returns different values on all other devices :

```
NSString *colId = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 0)];
    // NSLog(@"_userName = %@",_userName);

    NSString *authcode = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 5)];
    // NSLog(@"_emailID = %@",_emailID);

    NSString *title = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 1)];
    // NSLog(@"_contactNumber = %@",_contactNumber);

    NSString *subtitle = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 4)];

    NSString *hours = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 3)];
    NSString *notificationtype = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 2)];
```

For example: 
`NSString *title = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 1)];`
Here it will return title on iPhone 5 but on iPhone 5s it returns me authcode.

Comment: I need to detect this because i am using database in my app, when i use select query to select data from database it returns me a dictionary. On iphone 4 and 5 the index of values are different and on 5s and all other devices index are different. Therefore i want to detect the device.

Comment: @MuhammadUmair Don't use comment, update your question.

Comment: "On iphone 4 and 5 the index of values are different and on 5s and all other devices index are different" How can such a situation arise in the first place?

Comment: ok I 'll post new question for my problem.

Comment: I am going to update the question @rmaddy

Comment: @rmaddy I have updated my question

Comment: @rmaddy what i have done..? i don't understand.

Comment: when i try to get the value using column # it returns different value on different devices.
` NSString *authcode = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 5)];`

Comment: @rmaddy stackoverflow is not allow me to delete this question. And i am unable to post new question for next 90 min.

Comment: OK. At least update your question showing the actual query and clarify what is actually different between devices. It's not clear at all what you mean.

Comment: @rmaddy I have updated my question again, I hope i have clarify the actual query.

Comment: You still haven't updated your question with the actual query that you are using. Show the actual `SELECT` statement you are using.

Comment: @rmaddy Please check now

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112016/discussion-between-muhammad-umair-and-rmaddy).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never use `select * from ...` in a query. You have no idea what columns and in what order they will be returned.

Write your query with an explicit list of field names:

```
select userName, contactNumber, notificationType, ... from ...
```

This will ensure your index references are consistent and you know exactly what you will get.

Comment: Thank you so much for your precious time. It means alot. stay blessed. I got the problem.